# Sending multiple rows to function with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I have 8492 line (row) in csv file. In each iteration i need to send 1000 row to functionX, except the last iteration, it should send 1492 row (1000 and the remaining row less than 1000 row),i am asking how can i update my code to do that?

```
import pandas as pd

    Path_source_file = 'C:/Users/lap/Desktop/bone/Z1.csv' 
    row_count = len(open(Path_source_file).readlines())
    print(row_count)
    count = 1000    # number of sending dataset
    skip=0
    nraw = 1000
    no_cluster = 0
    for i in range(1,row_count+1):
        if count <= row_count  :

            dataset = pd.read_csv(Path_source_file, skiprows=skip ,nrows=nraw,header=None) 
            X = dataset.iloc[:,[0,0]].values
            functionX(X,i)
            no_cluster +=1
            count += 1000
            skip += 1000 
        if(no_cluster == 9):   

          break
```

Comment: Why not use `chunksize`?? ```for chunk in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/lap/Desktop/bone/Z1.csv', chunksize=count):
    print(len(chunk.index))```

Comment: chunksize send in each iteration 1000 , I need just the last iteration send 1000 + remaining row

Comment: yes, `chunksize` takes care of that, you get just the remaining rows in the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a massive file (8,492 seems reasonable), then you can read the entire lot and then create a grouping key and decrement the last key if it occurs less than N times, eg:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/lap/Desktop/bone/Z1.csv')
g = df.index // N
g = np.where((g == g[-1]) & ((g == g[g-1]).sum() < N), g[-1] -1, g)
for _, dataset in df.groupby(g):
    # ... do your things with dataset and functionX here...
```

With `pd.Series(list('abcde'))`, then N==2 gives you groups of [a,b] and [c,d,e], and with N==3 you get a single group of [a,b,c,d,e]

Answer (score 0):

In order not to read all the file at once, you still need to read 2 1000 chunks (which I assume you can do, since you can read 1000+999 in the worst case):

```py
import pandas as pd

Path_source_file = 'C:/Users/lap/Desktop/bone/Z1.csv' 
count = 1000    # number of sending dataset
chunk0 = pd.read_csv(Path_source_file, chunksize=count, header=None)
readLast = False
for chunk1 in pd.read_csv(Path_source_file, chunksize=count, header=None):
    if chunk1.shape[0] == 1000: # All but last iteration (except special case)
        data = chunk0
        chunk0 = chunk1
    else: # Last iteration
        data = chunk0.append(chunk1)
        readLast = True
    X = data.iloc[:,[0,0]].values
    functionX(X) # I removed the index i, I let you reimplement it if needed
if not readLast: # Special case with multiple of 1000, do the last chunk here.
    X = chunk0.iloc[:,[0,0]].values
    functionX(X) # I removed the index i, I let you reimplement it if needed
```